# Problems with csrftoken in Python

Tags: python, csrf

I'm trying to create a script which logs on automatically to the earthdata site because I want to download files from there, but I'm having trouble finding the right name for the csrf_token. When I run the script below it keeps giving me the following error: KeyError: "name='authenticity_token', domain=None, path=None"

Does anyone know how I find the right name is, or if I'm doing something else wrong here?
Thanks

```
    import requests
    from requests import session


    client = requests.Session()
    url = 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login'


    USERNAME = 'my_name'
    PASSWORD = 'my_pass'
    client.get(url)
    csrftoken = client.cookies['authenticity_token']

    payload = {
        'action': 'login',
        'authenticity_token' : csrftoken,
        'username': USERNAME,
        'password': PASSWORD,

    }

    with session() as c:
        c.post('https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/', data=payload)
        response = c.get('https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/profile')
        print(response.headers)
        print(response.text)'
```

Comment: You could print `c.cookies` and just see what's in there.

Comment: Also is that supposed to be `client.cookies`?  `c` does not appear to be defined at that point in your code.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be client.cookies. And when I print it, it says: <RequestsCookieJar[]>

Comment: You need to do a GET on the page and retrieve it from the hidden input field named *authenticity_token* and then do your POST.

Comment: I'm doing a GET on the page right? with client.get(url)? How do I retrieve it from the hidden input field?

Comment: It might not be a cookie; it might be a hidden field on the login form.

Comment: Do you know what i should change if it's a hidden field instead of a cookie?